# How can i add more space between links so that the whole button is showing?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS problem, my buttons is hiding the button below.

[image]

This is what a single button should look like[image]

Currently i have them wrapped in a paragraph

```
<p><a href="#" class="link">1. Aaahh!!! Real Monsters</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="link">2. ActRaiser</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="link">3. Addams Family Values</a></p>
```

The CSS for the buttons:

```
.link {
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 darkred;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .link:hover {
    background-color: #ce0606;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .link:active {
    box-shadow: none;
    top: 5px;
  }
```

How can I show the whole button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set style `display: inline-block;` for `.link`.

```css
.link {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 darkred;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.link:hover {
  background-color: #ce0606;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#" class="link">1. Aaahh!!! Real Monsters</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="link">2. ActRaiser</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="link">3. Addams Family Values</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-bottom to .link it serves as a space between the borders of the elements